# Starting a WCF from its own class constructor

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a self hosted named pipes (not using http) wcf hosted in a class library. I am able to start the WCF by using the following method in the class library:

```
ServiceHost serviceHost;
public void startService()
{
    // Create the service host
    ...
    // Open Service Host
    serviceHost.Open();
}
```

And then from a winforms test program running the following from a button click:

```
MyClassLib.MySvc testSvc;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testSvc = new MyClassLib.MySvc();
    testSvc.startService();
}
```

This does correctly start the WCF running in the class library.

But this requires the winforms that is referencing the class library to call startService method.

What I would like is just to be able to start the service as soon as a reference to the class library that will be running the WCF is done.

I have attempted to add the following in the class library service's constructor:

```
public MySvc()
{
    startService();
}
```

And then instantiate from the winforms:

```
MyClassLib.MySvc testSvc;
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    testSvc = new MyClassLib.MySvc();
    //testSvc.startService();  //No need to call this
}
```

If I debug the code, I can see that in fact it does break at this point:

```
public MySvc()
{
    startService();  // It does run this but service does not start
}
```

But this does not run the service.  Any help would be appreciated.

**Note #1**: I believe its some type of timing issue where it does not let you start the service during the constructor method but not sure of that.

Comment: You have a constructor for `MySvc`, but what in your code is calling that constructor? (Hint: probably nothing). You need some entry-point. Take a look at your Winforms application. There is a Program.cs file with a static `Main` method. That is the entry-point.

Comment: The constructor is the name of the service class in the class library.  And it is being called when I instantiate the class library from the winforms.  It even calls the startService method but the service does not start that way.

Answer (score 1):

Problem resolved and yes my assumption that it was a timing issue (See **Note# 1** above) was correct!

To replicate, change this:

```
public MySvc()
{
    startService();  // It does run this but service does not start
}
```

To this and problem solved:

```
public void delayStartService()
{
    Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith(t => startService());
}

public MySvc()
{
    delayStartService();
}
```

Comment: `Task.Delay(1000).ContinueWith` Does this make you feel right? Why 1000? Why not 10 or 10000? Will it work at every run?...

Comment: I could post a better one that doesn't depend on empirical timings, but not after this response...Go ahead with your solution.

Comment: You could then do so!  But do as you please buddy.